# How can I add multiple tags to the following scenario in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

How can I add multiple html tags to the following scenario in PhpStorm?

```
domain.com/uploads/2019/01/img-1.jpg
domain.com/uploads/2019/01/img-2.jpg
domain.com/uploads/2019/01/img-3.jpg
domain.com/uploads/2019/01/img-4.jpg
domain.com/uploads/2019/01/img-5.jpg
```

to

```
<img src="domain.com/uploads/2019/01/img-1.jpg"/>
<img src="domain.com/uploads/2019/01/img-2.jpg"/>
<img src="domain.com/uploads/2019/01/img-3.jpg"/>
<img src="domain.com/uploads/2019/01/img-4.jpg"/>
<img src="domain.com/uploads/2019/01/img-5.jpg"/>
```

I want to select a specific area and avoid editing the whole script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use multiple cursors functionality.

It's described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Multicursor.html) and I believe it gives you exactly what you need.

[image: Multiple cursors]

Comment: Glad I could help, I see you're new on this platform. 

Welcome! Hope you'll have nothing but a great experience here :)